# How to make 3d viewport available within a square?

Tags: c#, game-engine, unity-game-engine

How to make 3D Viewport within that 3D viewport square

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the *Normalized Viewport Rectangles*' approach, achieved by editing the `Viewport Rect` of the Camera.

[image]

The [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) explains an example of split screen for a two-player game. You can adapt the explanation having the game in a particular area, and the GUI in the other screen space.

> **Normalized Viewport Rectangles**
>
> Normalized Viewport Rectangle is specifically for defining a certain
> portion of the screen that the current camera view will be drawn upon.
> You can put a map view in the lower-right hand corner of the screen,
> or a missile-tip view in the upper-left corner. With a bit of design
> work, you can use Viewport Rectangle to create some unique behaviors.
>
> It’s easy to create a two-player split screen effect using Normalized
> Viewport Rectangle. After you have created your two cameras, change
> both camera’s H values to be 0.5 then set player one’s Y value to 0.5,
> and player two’s Y value to 0. This will make player one’s camera
> display from halfway up the screen to the top, and player two’s camera
> start at the bottom and stop halfway up the screen.
>
> [image]